# Copy portion of list

Tags: python

How do I copy only a portion of a list to another list. For example, if the length of the list is 105 but only 30 of the randomly selected elements need to be copied to a new list.
This is the code that I have written

```
for x in range (104):
            if len(trainingSet1)>30:
                  break
            trainingSet1[x]= (trainingSet[random.randint(1,103)])
```

But it keeps giving this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q1_2.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "Q1_2.py", line 72, in main
    trainingSet1[x]= (trainingSet[random.randint(1,103)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Judging by the names of your variables, I'd recommend looking at `sklearn`'s `train_test_split` function. Also, you can't guarantee uniqueness if you're accessing random indices like this.

Comment: Post the full `Traceback`

Comment: use the list's append function.  trainingSet1.append( trainingSet[random.randint(0,104)][-1])

Comment: try to use:    trainingSet1.append(trainingSet[random.randint(0,104)][-1])

Comment: What is the content of `trainingSet1`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about growing a list, but `trainingSet1 = [random.choice(trainingSet) for _ in range(30)]` will do the same as your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is probably here:

```
trainingSet1[x] = ...
```

Unless you already populated `trainingSet1`, you’re trying to assign to
an element that doesn’t exist yet. Use `trainingSet1.append(...)`
instead.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the trainingSet1 as `trainingSet1 =[]` and then try to append values to that instead of using `trainingSet1[x] = value` . If you really want to assign as you have done in the code you can first initialize the array as `trainingSet1 = [0] * 30`. This will assign 30 0's to the list and those will be replaced by your randomly selected values later.